# tag list database

Tags: php, database, upload, tags

i trying to set up a form that allows a users to upload an image to a folder on a server and the tags with it to a database so that images can be searched the tags and any selected image would display a list of tags connected to it. 
im trying to do a tag system like on stackoverflow just with images instead of text.
this is what i have so far:

```
<form action="insert.php" method="post">
<p>
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="imageName" id="imageName">
<br />
<label for="tags">Tags</label>
<textarea name="tags" id="tags" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
<input type="hidden" name="member" id="member" />
<br />
<input type="submit">
</p>
</form>
```

thats the form and this is the php

```
<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost");
if (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

mysql_select_db("images", $con);

$sql="INSERT INTO images (imageName, tags, member)
VALUES
('$_POST[imageName]','$_POST[tags]','$_POST[member]')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
 {
 die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
 }
echo "1 record added";

mysql_close($con);

     $allowedExts = array("jpg", "jpeg", "gif", "png");
$extension = end(explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]));
if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")
|| ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg"))
&& ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 200000000000000000000000)
&& in_array($extension, $allowedExts))
 {
  if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
   {
    echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
    }
   else
    {
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br>";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br>";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " kB<br>";
    echo "Temp file: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"] . "<br>";

    if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
      {
      echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
      }
     else
     {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
      "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      echo "Stored in: " . "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
      }
     }
    }
else
   {
   echo "Invalid file";
  }

  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by different ways:

Using Simple HTML drop-down list (with option allow multiple selection)

```
<select multiple="multiple" name="Select1" style="width: 129px">
<!-- start loop here-->
<option value="tag1">tag1</option>
<!-- end loop here-->
</select>
```

Here you need to load all tags from database.

OR
Use [jQuery UI Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/)

Comment: k thanks auto-complete was exactly what i was trying to do and i assume i can use a variable to search the tags from the database to auto-update the lists

Comment: its simple, just try to do it by your self, try using jquery ui, if you faces any issue, update this post...

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

`<input type="hidden" name="member" id="member" />`, you have not put the `value` attribute, which will contain the name of the member uploading the image/tags.

So change it to:

`<input type="hidden" name="member" id="member" value="YOUR_MEMBER_NAME_HERE" />`

Also, in PHP, `$_POST[imageName]` will not contain the uploaded image's name. There is separate superglobal array for this in PHP - `$_FILES`.

So, image name will be in `$_FILES['imageName']['name']`.

Also, you are only putting the image name in database, but not storing the image anywhere.

Here is the code to store the image.

```
$folder = 'NAME_OF_THE_FOLDER_WHERE_YOU_WANT_TO_SAVE_IMAGES';
if( is_uploaded_file( $_FILES['imageName']['tmp_name'] ) ) {
    move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['imageName']['tmp_name'], "$folder/" . $_FILES['imageName']['name'] );
}
```

As far as displaying already available tags to the user while uploading the images is concerned, you can ajaxify if by checking if the tags entered by the user are already present in the databases and if so, displaying them...and avoid repeatedly inserting them in the database.

This is a start and you can improve on it.

Hope it helps.

Comment: sorry i have that working i forgot to include it on this page as im just testing code to store the tags before i add it to the main page. the part im having an issue with is the tags to the database and how to retrieve them for searches and as a list on picture page